# SRSS/PowerBi Report Builder - Add Category Total to Bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I've built a report that shows a value for each region (Asia, Americas, EMEA) on a bar chart. I would like to have a fourth bar on the same chart that shows the overall value for all 3 regions.

I've been playing around with the category groups settings of the chart to understand if I could add a "group by" expression that would select all field values, but it doesn't seem to work.

I read elsewhere that I can use UNION but I'm not sure where to use that in PowerBI report builder? Is that adding a new dataset with a custom query? I don't think I can show values from a different dataset in my current chart.

I've avoided the problem for now by adding an extra chart just for the aggregate, but it's far from ideal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tried to create a calculated field, or to play with the category group settings, or adding a new category group called "All Regions" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you get your data in the dataset query.

If it's was a simple SQL query such as `SELECT Region, SUM(Value) AS Value From myTable GROUP BY Region`

then you could UNION the aggregate to this  with

```
SELECT Region, SUM(Value) AS Value From myTable GROUP BY Region 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  'All Regions' as Region, SUM(Value) AS Value From myTable
```

Comment: Thanks Alan. I've added the data via the Query Designer (PowerBI studio, I think the same exists in Visual Studio). The query that was generated is EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, selecting the columns I need from my PowerBI table. Do you know if there's a way to add the aggregate in this case? Perhaps I can use your SQL query to create a new dataset, but I have no idea if PowerBI databases support this.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a PowerBI dataset, which I know little about. My guess would be that you could do this in your query still. I would close this question then add a new question focusing on the query and having a total included with the results. Personally, I can help you there but I'm sure there will be plenty of people that can help with the DAX expression (or whatever language it is)